# What's the PMF of the Difference between 2 Independent Poisson RV?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I searched around and found that the difference between 2 independent Poisson RV $X_1$ (mean $\mu_1$) and $X_2$ (mean $\mu_2$) follows the Skellam distribution such that its PMF is:
$$f(k; \mu_1, \mu_2) = e^{-(\mu_1 + \mu_2)}(\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2})^{\frac{k}{2}}I_{|k|}(2\sqrt{\mu_1\mu_2})$$

where $I_{|k|}$ is a Bessel function...

and it gets quite complicated...

so erm... is there a simpler way to calculate something like e.g.
$$P(X_1 - X_2 = 1)$$
or
$$P(X_1 - X_2 < 2)$$
?

Comment: Is $k=x_2-x_1?$ If so, the first probability is just the case of $k=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly compute, then 
\begin{split}
P(X_1 - X_2 = 1)
&=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X_1-X_2 = 1|X_1 = k)P(X_1=k)
\\
&=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X_2 = k-1)P(X_1=k)
\\
&=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-\mu_2}\frac{\mu_2^{(k-1)}}{(k-1)!}e^{-\mu_1}\frac{\mu_1^{k}}{k!}
\\
&=
\frac{e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)}}{\mu_2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\mu_1\mu_2)^{k}}{k!(k-1)!}
\\
\end{split}
If we use the formula based on Bessel's function, then the infinite sum calculation will be subsumed into Bessel function computation.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X_1-X_2 = 1) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X_2=k, X_1=1+k)
& \text{by total probability, partitioning over $X_2=k$}
\\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X_2=k)\mathsf P(X_1=1+k)
& \text{by independence of the random variables}
\\
& =\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{\mu_2^k e^{-\mu_2}}{k!}\frac{\mu_1^{k+1}e^{-\mu_1}}{(k+1)!}
& \text{because }X_1\sim\mathcal P(\mu_1), X_2\sim\mathcal P(\mu_2)
\\
& = e^{-\mu_1-\mu_2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\mu_1^{k+1}\mu_2^k}{k!(k+1)!}
\\
& = e^{-\mu_1-\mu_2}\sqrt{\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}}I_1(2\sqrt{\mu_1\mu_2})
& \text{$I_1(z)$ is a Modified Bessel Function of the first kind}
\\[5ex]
\mathsf P(X_1-X_2 \leq z) & = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathsf P(X_2=k, X_1\leq z+k)
\\ & = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathsf P(X_2=k) \sum_{h=0}^{z+k}\mathsf P(X_1=h)
\end{align}$et cetera